# Is it possible to create new window using QML

Tags: qt, window, qml

Please help. Tried a lot to get a new window, when using QML, but it seems there is no such functionality.
Thanks!

This is what I have:
Qt Creator 2.4.1 
Based on Qt 4.8.0 (32 bit)

Built on Mar 21 2012 at 23:05:03

Comment: Can you elaborate your issue faced ?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I want to create a new window and I cannot do that using QML. Couldn't find any function which may help to create a **NEW** window in which I could display somethings in detail. Please check the question again, I have added my QT version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `Qt 5.0` and `QtQuick 2.0` there is the `QML` component [Window](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qml-qtquick-window2-window.html) which you can use to create new windows in your application. This component has been improved a lot in `Qt 5.2` see [5.2 documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html)

Comment: Thanks! I have checked and it should work fine. However, my question  is, is there any way to do the same using `Qt 4.8` and `QtQuick 1.1`?
This is since I have some limitations regarding upgradation of my Qt at this moment.

Comment: @Jino > Sorry I answered before you indicated your Qt Version. I guess it should be possible but maybe not with a default QML component. You might have to create a new Window yourself in C++

Comment: Thanks!! Will go ahead and check out some other methods!! ;)